# Two men run at $5$km/hr and $3$km/hr around a $6$km circular track. After how much time will they meet?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I am working on this problem.

> Two men, A and B run in the same direction around a circular track, starting at the same time from the same point. The speed of A is 5 km/hr and that of B is 3 km/hr. If the track has a perimeter of 6 km, after how much time will the two meet?

How to solve this question without using the concept of the relativity?

I believe the answer is 3.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid relativity? If you use relativity, you get that $B$ sits still and $A$ goes at $2$ km/hr and the problem reduces to how long does it take $A$ moving at $2$ km/hr to traverse $6$ kilometers.

Comment: @JohnDouma I needed proof of correctness for relativity method?

Answer (score 3):

It is approachable using simple modular arithmetic. We just wish to find the minimal positive solution $t$ of:

$$3t \equiv 5t \pmod 6$$

Which is solved when $3t - 5t = 6z$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows:

$3t - 5t = -2t = 6z \rightarrow t = -3z$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We consequently have the first nontrivial positive solution is 3.

*Note: if you are unfamiliar with "mod", it is akin to the remainder under integer division. What is occurring mathematically here then is essentially a "reset" when one makes a lap around the track, allowing us to evaluate the problem without relativity.*

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $3t-5t=\color{red}-2t$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, amended.

Answer (score 2):

To determine when the two men, A and B, will meet, we need to consider their relative speeds and the distance they need to cover to meet.

The relative speed between A and B is the difference in their speeds, which is $5 km/hr - 3 km/hr = 2 km/hr$. To find the time it takes for them to meet, we need to calculate the time it takes to cover the total distance of $6 km$ at a relative speed of $2 km/hr$.

$Time = Distance / Speed$

$Time = 6 km / 2 km/hr$

$Time = 3 hours$

Therefore, the two men will meet after $3$ hours of running.

Comment: This is the way I would solve this problem as well but the question was how to do this without relativity.